# jquery target a class with a symbol being used in it , how can i get working?

Tags: jquery

Have the existing HTML which cant be changed

```
<th class="#w"></th>
```

using css i can target this like so

```
th.\#w{display:none}
```

I need to target this using jQuery so i can remove all instances

I have tried

```
$('th.#w').remove();
$('.#w').remove();
$('#w').remove();
$('th.#w').remove();
$('th\\.#w').remove();
$('th\\#w').remove();
$('th\\\#w').remove();
$('th\\\.#w').remove();
$('\.#w').remove();
$('\\.#w').remove();
```

Comment: `$('[class="#w"]')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('th.' + $.escapeSelector('#w')).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <th class="#w">vcvcvc</th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$('th[class="#w"]').remove();
```